# Assist with returning js variable out of function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do something somewhat basic but not sure how to do it given the JS function I have.  I essentially want to "return" a js variable outside a js function so I can do stuff with it.  The function in question is a function written to capture an input to a modal and that is why it is written the way it is.

Here is the function:

```
<script>
$('#upload-images-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function gfunction1(e, f, g) {

  var yourParameter = e.relatedTarget.dataset.yourparameter;

  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = yourParameter;

});

</script>
```

It does pass the input to the modal and this function works with that, the output to "demo2" works as long as I do that statement within the function.

I would like to "pass" or "return" the variable outside of the function somehow.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? How do you plan to use that variable/value? Remember that the event handler is called whenever the event occurs, *some time in the future*!

Comment: Need a better explanation of what you want to do with it. It won't be available until event occurs. This sounds like an XY problem

Comment: hmmm - thanks for the input; i guess i did not get that; the function itself is triggered by the event so whatever it is that I want to do i would need to do within the function...at least i think that is what you guys are saying...

Answer (score 1):

You could define the function outside of event pattern. Not certain which variable you want to return?

```
<script>
    function gfunction1(e, f, g) {       
      var yourParameter = e.hasOwnProperty("relatedTarget")
                          ? e.relatedTarget.dataset.yourparameter
                          : e.dataset.yourparameter;        
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = yourParameter;
      // return variable
    }

    $("#upload-images-modal").on("show.bs.modal", gfunction1);
    // call function outside of event
    // pass `$("#upload-images-modal")[0]` as `e`
    gfunction1($("#upload-images-modal")[0]); 
</script>
```